# how do I enable a button if the option value inside a select tag is changed

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which there is a save button on each row.By default I keep all the save buttons disabled.What i am trying to do is to enable only the save button in a row if there is any change in the value  inside the select tag.

My table would be

```
<tr>
   <td id = "tst">${userId}</td>
   <td>${applicationId}</td>
   <td>${.firstName}</td>
   <td>${username}</td>
   <td class ="st" >
   <select id="roles" >
      <option value='Consumer'>Consumer</option>
      <option value='Contributor'>Contributor</option>
      <option value='Collaborator'>Collaborator</option>
      <option value='Coordinator'>Coordinator</option>
      <option value='Administrator'>Administrator</option>
    </select></td>
    <td style="width:90px">
    <div id = "usr_role" >
      <button  id = "${userId}" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"  disabled >Save</button>
    </div>
    </td>

</tr>
```

I have tried to check if the select value is changed using a function as follows:

```
 $("select").on('change' , function()
            {
             $('button ').prop('disabled', false);
                alert('select changed');
            });
```

This doesn't seem to be working ......can anybody suggest a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `tr` of the select and then the button inside it

```
$("select").one('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('button').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

---

If you have dynamically added rows

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('button').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, apply change event on every select box that are exists in table. Then find the row in basis of select box with the help of `closest()`, and change the button property that exists on the same row.

```
$('table tr').on('change', 'select', function() {
    var _parent = $(this).closest('tr');

    $('button', _parent).prop('disabled', false);
    alert('done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $("select").on('change' , function()
            {
             $('.btn-primary').each(function(){
                          $(this).prop('disabled', true);           
                                    });
             var id=$(this).attr('title');
             $('button#id'+id).prop('disabled', false);
                alert('select changed');
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
   <td id = "tst">${userId}</td>
   <td>${applicationId}</td>
   <td>${.firstName}</td>
   <td>${username}</td>
   <td class ="st" >
   <select id="roles" title="1">
      <option value='Consumer'>Consumer</option>
      <option value='Contributor'>Contributor</option>
      <option value='Collaborator'>Collaborator</option>
      <option value='Coordinator'>Coordinator</option>
      <option value='Administrator'>Administrator</option>
    </select></td>
    <td style="width:90px">
    <div id = "usr_role" >
      <button  id = "id1" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"  disabled >Save</button>
    </div>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
   <td id = "tst">${userId}</td>
   <td>${applicationId}</td>
   <td>${.firstName}</td>
   <td>${username}</td>
   <td class ="st" >
   <select id="roles" title="2">
      <option value='Consumer'>Consumer</option>
      <option value='Contributor'>Contributor</option>
      <option value='Collaborator'>Collaborator</option>
      <option value='Coordinator'>Coordinator</option>
      <option value='Administrator'>Administrator</option>
    </select></td>
    <td style="width:90px">
    <div id = "usr_role" >
      <button  id = "id2" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"  disabled >Save</button>
    </div>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Please try this it may help you